# CSS isn't linking to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I'm not able to link my external CSS to my HTML. I have this code in the head of my index.html file:

```
    <head>
        <title>Twenty by HTML5 UP</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
```

My file directory looks like this:

- /node-html

  - /views

    - /assets

      - /css

        - /main.css
    - /fonts
    - /js
    - /images
    - index.html
- index.js

How can I fix this?

Comment: extra `.` prob is the issue

Comment: index.html is at the same level as assets so "assets/css/main.css" should be fine

Answer (score 0):

index.html is the same level as assets. Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
```